# Trying to define GLOBAL variable not working PHP

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

hello im trying to define a global variable for different functions but im keep getting 
**failed to open stream** and i just can't find what is wrong. 
can you please help me to find what im doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
<?php
 $feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ArrolladoraLimonVEVO?alt=json";


function GetytTitle() {
    global $feedURL;
    $json = file_get_contents ('feedURL');
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    return $obj['entry']['title']['$t'];
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using your variable:

```
 $json = file_get_contents ('feedURL');
```

should be:

```
 $json = file_get_contents ($feedURL);
```

Now `file_get_contents` is looking for a file called `feedURL` in the directory of your script.